# How to open class file in IdeaVim through shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with IdeaVim. Usually I can open any class file by shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> without IdeaVim, which is really handy. However when I switched to IdeaVim, The shortcut doesn't work both in `Normal Mode` and `Insert Mode`. Neither can I find a settings option in the following dialog.
[image]

I'd really appreciate that if anyone can shed light on this issue. :)

Comment: Yep, there are 2 good options listed as answers below (from Rumid and from Andrey Vlasovskikh).  The screen shot you posted lists keys which have a conflict: they have an IntelliJ mapping and also an IdeaVIM mapping; it lets you choose whether these keys should be handled by  standard IntelliJ binding system or by IdeaVIM.  Use Rumid's answer if you want ^N to be handled by the IDE and work as it does without IdeaVIM, or use Andrey's answer if you want to bind a VIM-like shortcut to the same action.

Comment: @jbyler thank you, your suggestion is well summarized for the following answers. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You can use `:actionlist *class*` to find an IDE action for going to the definition of a class.
2. You can use the found action `:action GotoClass` as a Vim command-mode command.
3. You can map this command to any key combination in any Vim mode you want using the `:map` family of Vim commands, e.g. `:nmap ,c :action GotoClass<CR>`.
4. You can put your mapping command into ~/.ideavimrc so it'll load at startup:

~/.ideavimrc:

```
nmap ,c :action GotoClass<CR>
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly the way I want. Now I can put all ideavim related configurations into ~/.ideavimrc and source other vim settings from ~/.vimrc. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

Change handler(last column in this image) of this shourtcut to IDE.